# convert a string to JSON Object with same name (Need this for some sort of dynamic code in js)

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js

```
var ObjName = "Person"; 
 //If I assign "Institute" then I need Institute JSON object
//I have a global Person JSON with many attributes.
var thisObj = ObjName.toObject(); //need something of this kind

//I know eval can be used, but just checking any other better way to do this.
```

Please advise if there is better way to convert String to Object of its name in nodejs, sails js

Comment: Would it be a working alternative for you to use a property of a (e.g.) global object with that name? If so, you could write: myGlobalObj[ObjName] = {}; where ObjName still contains "Person" or "Institute" and access is done like myGlobalObj["Person"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not technically possible in ES5 JavaScript to do exactly what you want without the use of eval. As you have eluded to, it would **not** be a good idea to use eval in the this situation (or pretty much all). An alternative such as that which David suggested is probably a good go-to for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Set the variable
var ObjName = "person";

//define the initial object
var thisObj = {};

//Add some objects to it.
thisObj[ObjName] = {'things':'stuff'};

//Or, because we know the object name is 'person', attach stuff directly to it.
thisObj.person = 'test';

//Or, (again) if we need to reuse the variable as string later on
thisObj['person'] = 'test';
```